# Dynamicly add rows to TableLayout in separated files

Tags: java, android, layout, tablerow

I have got something like this:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/chooseBirthDateText"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                style="@style/mediumText"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="@string/choose_birth_date" />

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

i would like to add some more rows, but only after some time(lets say 10 sec). I thought to make those rows invisible at first and then make them appear. But in that way my scrollView is not working as i want(i can scroll down even if nothing is below - since rows are invisible)

So i thought to make rows that i want to add in second file, load them in middle time and add them after tableRow1 in moment they have to appear. Unfortunately i have got no idea how to do that(i am talking about connecting 2 files, not creating second one in java) :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two modes to hide a view:

- `INVISIBLE`: This view is invisible, but it still takes up space for layout purposes.
- `GONE`: This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout purposes.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility(int)

I think `GONE` will help you.

Comment: WOW. Awesome! Thx a lot, it's even better way than my request ^^

Answer (score 0):

You should try like this.let me know it is helpful or not?

```
    for(int i = 0; i < _attributeList.size();i++){


        TableRow newRow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
        newRow.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        newCheckBox = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());

                TextView feeTypeText = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                feeTypeText.setText(jsonObj.getString("feeType"));
                feeTypeText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                feeTypeText.setTextSize(16f);
                feeTypeText.setTypeface(tf);

                TextView dueAmountText = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                dueAmountText.setText(jsonObj.getString("dueAmount"));
                dueAmountText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                dueAmountText.setTextSize(16f);
                dueAmountText.setTypeface(tf);

                TextView dueDateText = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                dueDateText.setText(jsonObj.getString("dueDate"));
                dueDateText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                dueDateText.setTextSize(16f);
                dueDateText.setTypeface(tf);

                newRow.addView(newCheckBox,(new LayoutParams(0,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,0.8f)));
                newRow.addView(feeTypeText,(new LayoutParams(0,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,0.8f)));
                newRow.addView(dueAmountText,(new LayoutParams(0,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1.0f)));
                newRow.addView(dueDateText,(new LayoutParams(0,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1.0f)));
```

attributeTable.addView(newRow); }